# How to convert line of text into meaningful words

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I have a line of strings:

```
"specificationsinaccordancewithqualityaccreditedstandards"
```

Which needs to be split into tokenized words such as:

```
"specifications in accordance with quality accredited standards"
```

I have tried `nltk`'s `word_tokenize` but it was not able to convert,

**Context**: I am parsing a PDF document into text file, and this is the text which I am getting back from the pdf converter, to convert pdf into text I am using PDFminer in `Python`

Comment: Is there another PDF converter you can try?  It shouldn't be jamming all the words together like that.

Comment: you're most likely going to run into problems with ambiguity. For example: is the first word in that string "specific" (followed by "at" and "ion", both unique, valid words) or "specification"?

Comment: Did you try brute forcing your way by searching for all the words in the dictionary? Pretty sure you can find a library with all the words and in the English dictionary.

Comment: Yes this is what led me to find the solution, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion to solve this problem. First, you will want to download a dictionary txt file, which you can get here: https://github.com/Ajax12345/My-Python-Projects/blob/master/the_file.txt

```
dictionary = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('the_file.txt')]
def get_options(scrambled, flag, totals, last):
   if flag:
       return totals

   else:
       new_list = [i for i in dictionary if scrambled.startswith(i)]
       if new_list:

           possible_word = new_list[-1]
           new_totals = totals
           new_totals.append(possible_word)
           new_scrambled = scrambled[len(possible_word):]
           return get_options(new_scrambled, False, new_totals, possible_word)

        else:
            return get_options("", True, totals, '')


s = "specificationsinaccordancewithqualityaccreditedstandards"
print(' '.join(get_options(s, False, [], '')))
```

Output:

```
'specifications in accordance with quality accredited standards'
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thanks, also the dictionary can be dynamic as well and contain words which we already have found

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `trie`. A `trie` is a data structure that allows words validation. 
It is a tree, in which you navigate a branch for valid prefixes, and you get notified when you hit a full world.
Although I have never used it "concretely", I found this python implementation, [datrie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datrie/). 
My thought would be to import `datrie`, use it to generate a `trie` from a `txt` dictionary (e.g. [here](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words)) and then parse the string. Read character per character while you find matches in the `trie`, and when you don't you've reasonably found a word, then add it to the split words string.
You can find more on `trie` [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIjfhVPRZCg) (which is the one who taught me what a `trie` is).